# Can anyone find errors why the form fields is not showing in model from in django

Tags: python, django

> Can anyone tell me why in my home page the for is not showing ,the model form to signup user , I  make it using django UserCreationForm but home page it is not showing
> my `views.py` file  with import detaisl

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import signUpForm , LogInForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate ,login as auth_login ,logout as auth_logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render , HttpResponseRedirect
    def signup(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        fm=signUpForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            fm = signUpForm(request.POST)
            if fm.is_valid():
                fm.save()
                return redirect('home.html')
                
        else:
            fm = signUpForm()
        return render(request,"home.html" ,{'signupforms':fm})
```

> `home.html` here i just use bootstrap model and display form to signup use using model in

```
<div class="modal fade modelform" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header text-center ">
        <h5 class="modal-title text-dark" id="exampleModalLabel">Login using your credentials
</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      


<form action = '' method ='POST' novalidate >
{% csrf_token %}
{% for fm in signupforms %} 

<div class="form-group mt-0"> {{fm.label_tag}} {{fm}} <small class = 'text-danger'>{{fm.errors|striptags}}</small><br></div>
{% endfor %}


 <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <input class="btn btn-primary my-3" type="submit" value="Submit">

   </div>

 </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

> `forms.py`  where i create form and passing it to display  problem is this form is not showing in page

```
  from .models import loginForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms  import UserCreationForm   # AuthenticationForm ,UsernameField create default form 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
    
class signUpForm(UserCreationForm):
      name =forms.CharField(max_length=130 ,required=True ,label = 'Your Name',widget =forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':"form-control"}))
      email = forms.EmailField(required=True , max_length=130,widget =forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':"form-control"}))
      password1 = forms.CharField(label = 'Password', required=True,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={ 'class':"form-control"}))
      password2 =forms.CharField(label = ' Confirm  Password',required=True,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={ 'class':"form-control" }))
      
      class Meta:
         model = User
         fields  = ['name','email']
```

Comment: In the else statement in the views.py, after the line ."fm = signUpForm()" ..if you say print(fm) ..does it print the form correctly?

Comment: Also please show what are the imports for the signup in views.py

Comment: Is there any code to handle when `request.user.is_authenticated` is "True"? Is the user already logged in?

Comment: there is if  `not request.user.is_authenticated` and fill form to signup

Comment: the thing is why the form is not showing in model it is not showing  `signupForm` fields in model what my be the mistake

Comment: try `{{ signupforms }}` to see if anything is added to the page. I'd also add an else statement for `not request.user.is_authenticated` to see if that's the issue or not. Also how are you adding content to your modal?Are you using AJAX? if you are using AJAX, the process is different.

Comment: i'm using AJAX to get data it is just plain bootstrap model where i pass my signuplForm

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through "signupforms" but signupform is just a single element of your context:

```
View:
return render(request,"home.html" ,{'signupforms':fm})

Html:
{% for fm in signupforms %}
```

I am not 100% sure but I assume fm will be emtpy after the for tag